# How to perform abstract integration

Tags: integration

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space. [Here](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), page $124$, there is this sentence

> If $\mu$ is a finite support on $X$ we can define its barycenter $\beta(\mu)=\beta_X(\mu) \in X$ by 
>   $$\beta(\mu)=\int x d\mu$$

In the following Lemma $2.4$, it states that $\beta \delta = Id_X$, which I believe it to be $\beta \delta (x)=x$.

Question: How to apply the integral formula above to obtain the equation $\beta \delta = Id_X$? In other words, how to show

$$\beta(\delta(x))=\int x d\delta(x) = x$$

Comment: Your last equation is using $x$ for two different things, it'd better read $$\beta(\delta(x_0)) = \int_X \operatorname{id}_X\mathrm d\delta(x_0) = \int_X x\,\mathrm d\delta(x_0)(x)=x_0.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me try to clarify the notation.
For $x\in X$, $\delta(x)$ denotes the $\delta$ measure at the point $x$.
That is,
$$
\delta(x)(A)
=
\begin{cases}
1&x\in A\\
0&x\notin A
\end{cases}
$$
for $A\subset X$ and all sets are measurable.
When you integrate with respect to this measure, $x$ is a fixed parameter (which defines the measure), not a variable on integration.
Your definition of $\beta$ reads
$$
\beta(\mu)
=
\int_X y d\mu(y)
$$
for a measure $\mu$, and in the case $\mu=\delta(x)$ we get
$$
\beta(\delta(x))
=
\int_X y d(\delta(x))(y).
$$
I added parentheses for clarity and changed the variable of integration to avoid confusion.
Often one would write $\delta_x$ instead of $\delta(x)$.

The integral you take is a [Bochner integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) since its values are supposed to be elements in a Banach space.
Let us keep $x$ fixed.
Any function from the measure space $(X,\delta(x))$ to $X$ is Bochner measurable and Bochner integrability of $f:X\to X$ is equivalent with $\|f(x)\|<\infty$.
A simple calculation using the definitions in the Wikipedia article shows that if $f:X\to X$ is finite at $x$, then
$$
\int_X f(y)d(\delta(x))(y)
=
f(x).
\tag{*}
$$
(For the sequence of simple functions $s_n$, just take $s_n(y)=f(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $y\in X$.)

In our case $f$ is the identity function and thus the integral defining $\beta(\delta(x))$ is well defined as a Bochner integral and evaluates to $x$.

We have thus established that $\beta(\delta(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$.
Since $\delta$ is a function from $X$ to a certain space of measures on $X$ and $\beta$ is a function from that space of measures to $X$, the composition $\beta\circ\delta$ is a function $X\to X$.
The result states that this is actually the identity function on $X$: $\beta\circ\delta=Id_X$.
The function $\delta$ is not linear, so I would prefer to keep the circle in the composition (not writing $\beta\circ\delta$ as $\beta\delta$), but this is a matter of taste.
The function $\beta$ is linear if one considers signed measures so that the space of admissible measures becomes a vector space.

---

**Added remarks:**

- For any $x\in X$ our $\delta(x)$ is a measure.
  A measure takes sets as arguments and gives out numbers.
  Integration with respect to a measure (this or any other sufficiently regular measure) defines a functional from the space of continuous functions to the reals.
  That is, for a measure $\mu$ the functional is $f\mapsto \int_Xf(y) d\mu(y)$.
  Sometimes people identify a measure with the corresponding functional, but they are two different objects.
- More details on (*):
  Compare this presentation with the Wikipedia article; the notation is introduced there.
  Define a sequence $(s_n)$ of simple functions on $X$ simply by $s_n(y)=f(x)$ (or, equivalently, $s_n=f(x)\chi_X$).
  Every function is the same constant function.
  We have $\int_Xs_n(y)d(\delta(x))(y)=f(x)$.
  The function $X\to\mathbb R$ given by $y\mapsto\|f(y)-s_n(y)\|$ takes the value $0$ at $x$.
  Therefore $\int_X\|f(y)-s_n(y)\|d(\delta(x))(y)=\|f(x)-s_n(x)\|=0$.
  (This is just the usual integral with respect to a delta measure, not a Bochner integral.)
  Using the definition of the Bochner integral, we have
  $$
  \int_Xf(y)d(\delta(x))(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xs_n(y)d(\delta(x))(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x)=f(x).
  $$
- Often people allow functions also to take infinite values.
  If the function $f$ is really a function $X\to X$ and not $X\to X\cup\{\infty\}$ for an"abstract infinity $\infty$", then of course $\|f(x)\|<\infty$ for all $x$ because all points have finite norm.
- Any measure can be converted into a functional as described above.
  If this conversion is done for the measure $\delta(x)$, one obtains the evaluation functional at $x$.
  This is what equation (*) says.

Comment: In your first sentnece, shouldn't $\delta_x : Lip_0(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$? In other words, why the domain of $\delta_x$ is subset of $X$?

Comment: Can you show how to obtain $\int_X f(y)d(\delta(x))(y) = f(x)$?

Comment: @Idonknow, I added some details to the end of my answer. These should address both of your questions.

Comment: I still don't understand why $\delta(x)$ is a measure on $X$. Isn't $\delta(x)$ is an evaluation functional on $Lip_0(X)$?

Comment: @Idonknow, you can convert any measure into a functional as I wrote. If you do this conversion for the measure $\delta(x)$, you get the evaluation functional at $x$. If you identify the measure and the corresponding functional, then $\delta(x)$ is an evaluation functional, but I think this identification can be confusing. Wikipedia gives a nice discussion about the "delta function" as a measure and integrating with that measure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure (Changing $\mathbb R$ to $X$ doesn't change the most basic things.)

Comment: Now everything makes sense.....